# jQuery Drill Down iPod Menu FOUC and Selecting Current page

Tags: jquery, menus, css

I'm using [Drill Down Ipod Menu](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-drill-down-ipod-menu) and I'm really like the style of showing submenus , but I have two problems with it.

1-when i load a page it shows all submenus open for a second and I experience a Flash of Unstyled Content , it was good for a while when I changed style css but it backed again (i don't know if there's a relation between css file and the problem). my list of active plugins is below (I had some others that i deleted them):

1-Bulk Post Creator Plus
2-Cat + Tag Filter
3-Category Grid View Gallery
4-cforms
5-Custom Field Template
6-ShowID for Post/Page/Category/Tag/Comment
7-SwfObj
8-vSlider
9-wp-jalali

how can I prevent showing my menu unstyled ?

2- when I navigate from a submenu to my homepage (from a link outside of menu) menu stay in previous state , i know it use cookies , but is there anyway to show current page instead of using cookies ?

if it's impossible to solve this problems what plugin can I use instead to have folding menus from wordpress custom menus (not pages and categories ) ?

sorry for my bad english
thanks in advancce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to consult the author of plugin since it's using a custom jQuery plugin script.

> how can I prevent showing my menu un styled?

You can add a class of `no-display` to the elements of the menu that are un styled as the page loads then in css set `.no-display {display:none;}`Then use jQuery to remove the `no-display' class when the page is loaded right before it calls the plugin javascript.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#parent-div').removeClass("no-display");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks to chris for the idea , my problem has solved as following instruction :

1- For the un styled view :
I tried use `display:none;` but there was problems happening in showing menu (no content showing after remove it or change "none" to "block" , so I've added below style to my sidebar in sidebar.php :

```
<div id="sidebar" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:-9999px; ">
```

it will create my menu but showing in in a place that no one can see , next i've removed style in footer (when everything loaded) using jquer (right before  and after `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`):

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() { $('div#sidebar').removeAttr('style'); });
$('div#sidebar').addClass("sideshow");


});
</script>
```

now there is no FOUC even in dial-up connection !

2- for the menu state problem :
drop drill ipod menu using cookies to save last menu state , so i've added following code to header to delete cookies in certain pages (right after `<div id=header>`):

```
<?php if(is_page(array(22,35,13,27,67))){ ?>

<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
$.cookie('dd-wrapper-0','');
});
</script>

<?php } ?>
<?php if(is_front_page()){ ?>

<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
$.cookie('dd-wrapper-0','');
});
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

work like a Charm !

now menu restart to default state in homepage and selected page.

Comment: Great that you were able find a workable solution.  Good job.